# Rails routes: optional parameters in resourceful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Does anyone know if there is a way to add optional parameters to a URL for a given resource? That is, given:

```
resources :cars
```

in the routes fiel, I'd like to have the year optionally attached to the end of the URL:

```
mysite.com/cars/coolcar/2015
mysite.com/cars/coolcar # Both point to the same resource
```

I know I could get along with the usual, non-resourceful routes:

```
get 'cars/:id(/:year)'
```

But i'd like to know if there is a more 'elegant' way of doing it, since in my case it might need quite a lot of routes with optional params.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
resources :cars do
  member do
    get ':year', to: 'cars#show'
  end
end
```

Not sure if you'd class it as more elegant though

Comment: By elegant I meant less verbose. This will do the trick, thanks a lot.